# A question related to the usage of LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}

Tags: functions, legending, options, documentation, undocumented

I saw this piece of code from an answer by @Syed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267061/stacking-lines-of-text-in-a-linelegend/267064?noredirect=1#comment665705_267064).

```
LineLegend[{Blue, Green, Red}, {"a = test1\na = test2", 
  "a = test3\na = test4", "a = test5\na = test6"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 15}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 
    15}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 15}}]
```

At first, I noticed `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}` which is new to me.
 So I checked the documentation for [LegendLayout](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout.html) and didn't see any example where they used something like `{"Row", 1}`. 
 After that I tried the code and changed `{"Row", 1}` to `{"Row", 2}` and `{"Row", 3}` and finally realized that this number indicates number of rows.

Question: 
Does this usage exist in the documentation as I don't really see it? 
 If not then how would you learn something like this, from books, someone or just discover it by accident? 
 I know this is very simple for most of you but it's confusing for a beginner like me.

Comment: @Syed as you are the person who wrote it can you answer the question?

Comment: I recall seeing this usage in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265145/making-justify-perfect-alignment-in-the-plotlegend) answer by @kglr.

Comment: @kglr I wonder if you could give some information.

Comment: Perhaps a noteworthy comment: it seems that `LegendLayout` shares the same options settings as `PlotLayout`, i.e `{Or["Column","Row"], n}` with `n` a positive integer. It was used [`here`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-ib7yR13Yk&t=777s) for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no other answers, I will venture something. It is not a full answer, but I think the links and comment-like structure might be useful.

This is an **undocumented** option for [`LegendLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout.html). As it has been pointed out by the author of the OP it works like so:

```
LegendLayout -> {"Row", # of rows}
```

and likewise for columns and, of course, their reversed versions.

The oldest post on this site that I managed to find about this matter is the answer by [`rcollyer`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77151/straightforward-way-to-make-a-multicolumn-line-legend).

There's another, earlier, mention of undocumented options for [`LegendLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout.html) - see [`this`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica) thread, though not as explicit as the first link. However, in the latter link you can find various ways of going about finding and understanding these things.

From the link above I suggest that you adopt the answer by [`Mr.Wizard`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica/810#810); namely using `// Trace // InputForm` and then following the logic outlined thereof.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know that it's undocumented option. I always wonder how can they miss not document this important option.

Comment: I tried `Plot[{x, 1 + x}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] // 
  Trace // InputForm` and see `LegendLayout -> "Column"` but it doesn't really show the option for number of columns.

Comment: @emnha I am not quite sure why some options are left undocumented to be honest. And I cannot begin to imagine a reason. I am pretty sure that there is one, I just don't see it. With regards to the second comment, I will try to work more on that and get back later in the week :)